# How do I exclude my break statement from this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner coder here trying to get past a challenge. I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user for a list of numbers and then prints the maximum and minimum values from that list. I realize that there are built in functions to do this in Python but I have defined my own to try and better grasp the logic and how the language works. Here is what I have so far:

```
def find_largest_number(nums):
    largest_number = nums[0]
    for number in nums:
        if number > largest_number:
            largest_number = number
    return largest_number


def find_min_number(nums):
    min_number = nums[0]
    for number in nums:
        if number < min_number:
            min_number = number
    return min_number


nums = []
while True:
    num = input("> ")
    nums.append(num)
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        value = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue

print(find_largest_number(nums))
print(find_min_number(nums))
```

If I run this code I can successfully get the minimum number, however the break statement 'done' is always returned as the largest number. Is there a way to exclude it from the functions or something else that I am missing? I have tried adding an int() before the num in both of the functions but this just causes the program to crash with the following error: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

location:

```
def find_largest_number(nums):
    largest_number = nums[0]
    for number in nums:
        if int(number) > largest_number:
            largest_number = number
    return largest_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the line `nums.append(num)` so that it goes right after the line `value = int(num)` and then edit it so that it reads `nums.append(value)` instead.

Currently, you are appending the input `num` to the list before checking to see if it is really the signal value `"done"`.  You really want to wait until after verifying that it is not `"done"` before appending.

Secondly, you want to convert the `num` to an actual number (an int) which you are already doing when you say `value = int(num)`.  Now, `value` is the integer (numeric) version of the input, and that is what you really want to append to your list.

The problem with not converting the `num` from a string to an int is that the comparison operators like `<` and `>` work differently on strings and ints.  Strings are compared using alphabetical order, and so, for example, `'b'` goes after `'aa'`.  But if these were numbers, we would want the opposite behavior, since `2` should come before `11`.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed for some other reason. Andrew's right here; it's about appending the input only after you've evaluated it to be a number you want to compare.

Comment: In this code ```num``` and ```number``` are both strings which is why you get the type error when ```num == `done'``` and trying to ```int(num)```.

My approach would be to validate the input right at the stage of input so that the rest of the input processing is with integer type.

Comment: I have no idea why it was closed either, apparently it was associated with another question that isn't the same or anywhere near as specific. I appreciate the help though folks! Thanks for the detailed explanations

Comment: @ShawnRamirez do you mean writing at this statement: num = int(input("> ") - ? I tried this and it resulted in the program crashing if I tried to enter the break statement 'done'